# Why shortcuts are not created?

Tags: powershell

i have trouble in powershell (Windows 10 1809)
I want that this script seach all .exe files in my directory D:\Test in Recursive mode and make shortcuts in D:\ . But my code just creating link.lnk in D:\ . Why?

```
$1 = get-childitem "D:\Test" -recurse | where {$_.extension -eq ".exe"} | % {
Write-Host $_.FullName
}
ForEach ($item in $1)  {
$Shell = New-Object -ComObject ("WScript.Shell")
$ShortCut = $Shell.CreateShortcut("D:\link.lnk")
$ShortCut.TargetPath= $1
$Shortcut.Save()
}
```

Comment: I guess you are overwriting your shortcut with every exe that is found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are naming all of the shortcuts `D:\link.lnk`, and the loop will just overwrite the same name over and over. Specifying a unique shortcut link filename using the `BaseName` property (name minus the extension) should solve your problem. Also you need to use the loop `$item` to specify the `TargetPath`.

Also, the by looping through with the `Write-Host` you don't actually assign anything to your variable `$1`. By removing the `% { Write-Host $_.FullName }` `$1` does get the proper output. So the proper code should be:

```
$1 = get-childitem "D:\Test" -recurse | where {$_.extension -eq ".exe"}

ForEach ($item in $1)  {
    Write-Host "Creating Shortcut: D:\$($item.BaseName).lnk  Pointing to: $($item.FullName)"
    $Shell = New-Object -ComObject ("WScript.Shell")
    $ShortCut = $Shell.CreateShortcut("D:\$($item.BaseName).lnk")
    $ShortCut.TargetPath= $item.FullName
    $Shortcut.Save()
}
```